# how to fetch the MIPS-opcode from the hex

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, mips, mips32

How do I calculate the leftmost 6 bits from numbers like `0x71014802`
These 6 bits tell us what MIPS instruction this code represents.
The answer is `0x1c`  but how does the book calculate it?

Example:

```
0x10001A08 = 000011 00000 10000 01000 00000 000111
```

How was this `71014802` been converted into binary? How do I accomplish this?

Comment: sorry I read c but was assembly... I did not understand the question.

Comment: Edited !! Please read my edit

Comment: Done, Check if I understood your requirement, put comment below there in case.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is an hex number it is straightforward to convert it into binary. Every HEX digit can be converted in 4 binary digit as in the following example

```
Ex $$_7=2^2+2^1+2^0=0111_$$
```

For your hex number 0x71014802 is

```
0x71014802 => 0111 0001 0000 0001 0100 1000 0000 0010
                 7    1    0    1    4    8    0    2
```

Regarding to a conversion from decimal to binary I suggest you converting the decimal in hex and then hex to binary, let's do an example with a decimal (I choose 71014802 DEC)

```
71014802 => 0x43B9992 => 0000 0100 0011 1011 1001 1001 1001 0010
                            0    4    3    B    9    9    9    2
```

another way to convert a decimal number into a binary one is by dividing by two and picking the remainder... but it is a longer procedure (you can find it [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary))

Anyway if the opcode is in a fixed position (26-31) the opcode  can be simply obtained through a mask and shift right as follow:

```
opcode=(reg>>26)&0x3F
```

An algorithm to print a binary number can be like this:

```
void print_binary(int n) {
   while (n) {
      char bit = n & 0x1;
      putchar (bit+'0');
      n >>= 1;
   }
   putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: how to convert this 71014802 to binary ?

Comment: Isn't this what I show you above? are you asking for an algo? I can add you here an algo to do that, or you may simply use the calculator on your machine and put "programmer mode". I added here a function to print the binary

Comment: Understood.... I added here an algo to print the binary of any 32 bit number @user3025956. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
char bits = (num >> (sizeof(num)*8 - 6)) & 0x3F;
```

`0x3F = 00111111` that's six bits pushed all the way to the left, giving you the result you're looking for.

**EDIT**: An more detailed explanation.
What we are trying to do is to get the six leftmost bits of an integer. To determine if a bit is flipped or not (i.e. 1 or 0) we `and` it with `1`. Getting six bits of a number is done by constructing an integer with six flipped bits, `00111111`, or `0x3F`, and `and`ing it with our number like so: `num & 0x3F`. This will give the six **righmost** bits of the integer, to get the bits on the left side, we shift our number all the way to the left, and run the same `and` operation: `(num >> (sizeof(num)*8 - 6)) & 0x3F`.

```
$ cat temp.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t num = 0x71014802;
    char c = (num >> (sizeof(num) * 8 - 6)) & 0x3F;
    printf("0x%X\n", c);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc temp.c && ./a.out
0x1C
```

**EDIT2**: My math was a bit off, that's what you get for browsing SO after midnight... Updated.

Comment: can you please explain this

Comment: Edit the main post with an explanation.